# isosceles right-angled triangles defined on an infinite Go board by same-colored stones

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

You start with an infinite Go board. On every point of the board you place one colored stone. There are n>1 different colors. Find all natural numbers n that no matter how the stones colored, three stones of the same color form the vertices of a isosceles right-angled triangle. The catheti (legs) of the isosceles right-angled triangles must me be on the lines of the board.

This question is already answered for [right-angled triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898846/triangles-defined-on-an-infinite-go-board-by-same-colored-stones).

Comment: For both questions, it is enough to invoke the Hales-Jewett theorem. As soon as the number of colors is finite, there always is a square with monochromatic vertices.

Comment: For documentation purposes, the non-isosceles variant was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898846/triangles-defined-on-an-infinite-go-board-by-same-colored-stones) and the origin of this problem is a [contest](https://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/bwm/aufgaben/aufgaben-2018/aufgaben-18-2.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

I will sketch an elementary argument for $n=2,3$ and let you extend it to the general case.
In the following lines, for brevity, *triangle* stands for a set of the $\{(a,b),(a,b+c),(a+c,b+c)\}$ kind with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $c\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

---

$n=2$.
Let us consider the points $(x,x)$ together with their colors: by the Van Der Waerden theorem we may assume that 
$$ (0,0),(d,d),(2d,2d)$$
all have the same color (i.e. we have a monochromatic $3$-AP), say white. If one of the points
$$(0,d),(d,2d)$$
is white we are done, hence we may assume they are black. In such a case the point $(0,2d)$ completes a monochromatic triangle no matter what.

---

$n=3$.
Let us consider the points $(x;x)$ together with their colors: by the Van Der Waerden theorem we may assume that 
$$ (0,0),(d,d),(2d,2d),\ldots,(Nd,Nd)$$
all have the same color (i.e. we have a monochromatic $(N+1)$-AP), say red. If one of the points
$$(0,d),(d,2d),\ldots((N-1)d,Nd)$$
is red we are done, hence we may assume they all are green or blue. If $N$ is large enough we have a monochromatic $3$-AP among the previous points, which we may assume to be
$$(kd,(k+1)d),((k+1)d,(k+2)d),((k+2)d,(k+3)d)$$
made by green points. If one of the points
$$ (kd,(k+2)d),((k+1)d,(k+3)d)$$
is either red or green we are done, hence we may assume they are both blue. But in such a case we have a monochromatic triangle with a vertex in $(kd,(k+3)d)$.

[image]

*Addendum*: this can be easily turned into a proof of the Hales-Jewett theorem for monochromatic squares in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. The argument above shows that in any $M\times M$ square (for an explicit, huge $M$) there is a monocromatic $|\overline{\phantom{a\,}}$, which can be positioned in $\leq M^4$ ways in the $M\times M$ square. It follows that by diagonally stacking $\leq M^4+1$ squares $M\times M$ we surely find two monochromatic $|\overline{\phantom{a\,}}$ with the same relative position. By diagonally stacking more $M\times M$ squares, we surely find two monochromatic $|\overline{\phantom{a\,}}$ with the same relative position and the same color. By diagonally stacking more $M\times M$ squares, we surely find a $k$-AP of monochromatic $|\overline{\phantom{a\,}}$ with the same relative position. We finish by considering the color of the missing square vertex in any $|\overline{\phantom{a\,}}$ and by applying induction on $n$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't understand, why we can consider the points as $(x;x)$.

Comment: @C.Podolski: why shouldn't we? They are just the points along the "main" diagonal of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Probably a very stupid question: But why we can assume that both axes are the same?

Comment: @C.Podolski: I do not understand your question. We are not assuming any similarity here, just selecting some points from the main diagonal. The set $\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ can be completed to a right-angled, isosceles triangle with legs parallel to the axis by considering $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$. Anyway, please have a look at my comment under your other, [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898846/triangles-defined-on-an-infinite-go-board-by-same-colored-stones).

Comment: OK. I think of it like we apply Van der Waerden's theorem on both axes, but how we can than be sure that $d$ is on both the same? Sry for being such a hard case.

Comment: @C.Podolski: I guess you didn't really read my proof. I am not applying VDW on both axis, I am applying VDW on the diagonal and working from there.

Comment: And would you generalize this for all natural $n$?

Comment: @C.Podolski: as $n$ increases, you just need to apply VDW and sifting more times, but the general approach for finding a monochromatic triangle stays the same.

Comment: Which $N$ is meant here $(0,0),(d,d),(2d,2d),…,(Nd,Nd)$?

Comment: @C.Podolski: any number large enough to ensure it is possible to extract a monochromatic $3$-AP from $(0,d),\ldots((N-1)d,Nd)$. In other terms, $N$ is the suitable VDW number.